# Which version of pgAdmin started to use the master password?

Tags: pgadmin, pgadmin-4

Does anyone know which version of pgAdmin was the first to use the master password? I didn't see this change in the changelog. The only thing I found was that there was a fix in version [4.15](https://www.pgadmin.org/docs/pgadmin4/development/release_notes_4_15.html):

> Issue #4341 - Give appropriate error messages when the user tries to use an blank master password.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was introduced in version [4.7](https://www.pgadmin.org/docs/pgadmin4/development/release_notes_4_7.html):

> Issue #4184 - Added Master Password to increase the security of saved passwords.